# Reading a .plist file that's hosted online

Tags: objective-c, info.plist

I'm working on an app that would require to update a .plist file every couple of months, i don't what to resubmit the app everytime for that, so is their a way to host the .plist file online and have the app call it for updates? I tried using NSURLConnection (or maybe i didn't setup it right) but that didn't work... any other ideas? Here is example file that i'm using http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/TestData.plist
as always thanks in advance, here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *mainDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NewsSources" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

How can i change the code so i can access the file that is hosted online?

Comment: Why didn't `NSURLConnection` work? It should work if done properly. Update your question with your `NSURLConnection` attempt.

Comment: as for NSURLConnection i used:
    'NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/TestData.plist];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/TestData.plist];'

Comment: As I said, update your question. Don't post code in comments.

Comment: it won't let me update the comment since i'm new...

Comment: You don't want to update the comment (no one can update a comment after 5 minutes). You need to edit your own question which anyone can do.

Comment: man didn't realize this was that complicated... i thought with the line of code i gave an easy enough answer was available... all i need is the right code, either using NSURLConnection or whatever else. If their is no answer just let me know... thx

Comment: It's not that there's no answer. It's that we want to help you improve your question to make it easier for someone to answer precisely. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on what we're trying to achieve. I personally don't know the answer to your question, but I'm sure there are people who do. If you can make our lives easier by making your question high quality, we can make your life easier with a high-quality answer and everyone wins :)

Comment: I don't know what you really ask here, becase I don't know which file you'd like to update... updating file in the _bundle_ is not possible as you cannot override anything in the bundle, but you said the `NSURLConnection` fails, but you said nothing about the _how_. so... I feel your question needs to be more clarified.

Comment: i tried to explain it as best as i could, i'm only a newbie - thanks anyways homie Larme answer the question to a tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .plist from your address example is a `NSArray` at top level, not a `NSDictionary`. If you try and try with it, you'll fail if you want a `NSDictionary`.

Its content clearly shows it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array> <================= *** HERE ***
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Batman Begins</string>
        <key>coverImage</key>
        <string>batman_begins.png</string>
        <key>featureLength</key>
        <integer>140</integer>
        <key>releaseDate</key>
        <date>2008-07-08T23:32:07Z</date>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>The Dark Knight</string>
        <key>coverImage</key>
        <string>dark_knight.png</string>
        <key>featureLength</key>
        <integer>152</integer>
        <key>releaseDate</key>
        <date>2008-12-10T00:32:07Z</date>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>The Prestige</string>
        <key>coverImage</key>
        <string>prestige.png</string>
        <key>featureLength</key>
        <integer>130</integer>
        <key>releaseDate</key>
        <date>2007-02-21T00:32:07Z</date>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

You can use:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/TestData.plist"]];
```

If the plist (you want to use) is really a `NSDictionary` at top level, you can use a similar approach:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"linkToNSDictionaryTopLevel.plist"]];
```

Comment: I just read the doc and methods available of NSArray and NSDictionary.

Comment: It's still Chinese to me bro... but now i can see where i went wrong thanks!