# Read .plist from server in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

Although I understand that using `JSON` would be a better implementation for what I'm trying to do, I'm still learning and want to get my app "working" just for testing.

Currently my app reads from a .plist file at a few points and I want to host this on a server, so that I can update values without having to update the app!

I've tried various workarounds for this, but none have seemed to work so far.

```
if let arrayQuote = NSArray(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Data", ofType: "plist")!)
```

Is there a way from reading this plist from a `URL` and if so, how can it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `arrayWithContentsOfURL` The code is in Objective-C, but that's the same issue (and should be easily translated): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281206/reading-a-plist-file-thats-hosted-online/31811322#31811322

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to use `NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"linkToNSDictionaryTopLevel.plist"]];` - How do I then translate it to Swift?

Comment: Is it an `NSArray` of a `NSDictionary` at top level? If array (method equivalent exists for both): `let arrayQuote = NSArray(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string:myURLForThePlist))`

Comment: To load data from the internet it's recommended to use an asynchronous way like `NSURLSession` rather than the synchronous method `contentsOfURL`. If an error occurs the synchronous way blocks the UI.

Comment: Thanks both. That makes sense. I will try and get it working using the first method, then look at NSURLSession... Wouldn't want the app to crash if it didn't load.